# I need to convert .doc and .docx files to .pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, converters, doc

I need to convert .doc and .docx files to .pdf using python . ***I have seen some answers already available but that are using comtypes and opening WordApplication. I can not do that.*** 
What I seek is a way of doing it using some python libraries that preserves font , tables , heading size and images etc , **without opening MS Word or LibreOffice or anything like that**
Converting .doc and .docx files to some intermediate format(and later converting that format to pdf) would be fine too , if needed . Please help me with the code or guided instructions(I am not a pro in python) I should follow.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Why don't you want to open MS Word?

Comment: Tool/product/tutorial recommendation questions are expressly off-topic for Stack Overflow. You'll need to choose one that's right for you. And also: this isn't a free code-writing service, and your question reads as "write this code for me" - that's not the purpose of the site.

Comment: https://pandoc.org/ supports docx but not doc.  Is that good enough?

Comment: @user202729 Because this service will be hosted on servers , which will not be having third party applications

Comment: @JohnZwinck please share the method/code for .docx . I will figure out for .doc some other way

Comment: Hii , @DavidMakogon  i just wanted to get knowledge from anyone who has encountered the same problem statement. I not necessarily need code even the steps or any source of help would do

Comment: I dont understand the downvote, I've the same issue, the security guys are not allowing to install any kind of desktop software in a server (no matter how you try to explain it, they are bound to the "unsecure" argument), so I'm stuck with the "no office tools" to produce a pdf from doc, got here because of the same explained here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been in the similar problem earlier,

My suggestion:

sorry there is no such direct python library to handle Microsoft office formats specially (.doc)

So try to use LibreOffice as a service in Ubuntu its "libreoffice"
if windows its "soffice.exe" use this in command line to convert the document to .PDF without opening LibreOffice

and its easy and fast too and more over gives almost perfect conversion of the file.

A sample:

For Windows:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to pdf "input_file_path" --outdir "output_dir_path"
```

This will convert the input file into pdf in the given output directory without opening the LibreOffice ans just using it as a service.

To run this command from python you can use "subprocess" like libraries.